# Optimization Problem with light intensity

Tags: calculus

In a street, two lamp posts are $300$ ft apart. The light intensity at a distance $d$ from the first lamp post is $1000/d^2$ , the light intensity at distance $d$ from the second (weaker) lamp post is $125/d^2$. In both cases the light intensity is inversely proportional to the square of the distance to the light source).

The $\text{combined light intensity}$ is the sum of the two light intensities coming from both lamp posts.

a) If you are between the lamp posts, at distance $x$ ft from the strong light, then given a formulate for the combined light intensity coming from both lamp posts as a function of $x$

b) Where is the combined light intensity the smallest?

Comment: Are you able to make any progress on these problems? Like, can you write an expression giving the intensity of the light a distance of $d_1$ from the stronger light (noting that you'd be $d_2=300-d_1$ away from the weaker light)?

Comment: The lamp posts have negligible height?

Answer (score 1):

$a) I(x) = \dfrac{1000}{x^2} + \dfrac{125}{(300-x)^2}$

$b) I'(x) = -\dfrac{2000}{x^3}+\dfrac{250}{(300-x)^3} = 0 \iff 8(300-x)^3 = x^3 \iff 2(300-x) = x \iff x = 200$ ft. Thus $I$ is minimized when you are at $200$ ft from the strong intensity  lamp post.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) If you are on the line with endpoints on the lamps, and you are $x$ ft. from the strong light, then you are $300-x$ ft. from the weak lamp. You can then find the light intensities and add them

b) You want to minimize

$$\frac{1000}{x^2}+\frac{125}{(300-x)^2}$$
Take the derivative of this, which is
$$\frac{250}{(300-x)^3}-\frac{2000}{x^3}$$
and equate it to $0$.